# Sort records by referring records from another table rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have following tables

```
users (id, name, email, pricing_plan_id)
products (id, name, desc, slug)
pricing_plans (id, name, desc)
tagged_products (id, product_id, pricing_plan_id)
```

For more details please find attached screen shot
[image]

User can see ALL the products into the products section. Now I have to sort the products by referring the tagged_products tables.

Lets say user1 has pricing_plan_id = 1 then he can see the products that are tagged under given pricing_plan_id first and then remaining products.

For example user1 can see products in following sequence
[p3,p1,p2,p4,p5,p6,p7]

I tried following query but no luck

```
Product.joins("LEFT JOIN tagged_products AS tp ON tp.products_id=products.id AND tp.pricing_plan_id=#{user.id}").order('tp.product_id desc')
```

I am getting the result but ordering is not working.

Can any one help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you update your query and use this instead:

```
Product.joins("LEFT JOIN tagged_products AS tp ON tp.products_id=products.id AND tp.pricing_plan_id=#{user.id}").order('tp.products_id desc')
```

.order('tp.product_id desc') -> .order('tp.product**s**_id desc')

Given your data, this SQL query should do it:

```
SELECT * from `products` LEFT JOIN tagged_products AS tp ON tp.product_id=products.id AND tp.pricing_plan_id=1 ORDER BY product_id desc
```

Here is the sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a282/4